# SQL: Sum of two columns containing NULLS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation

I want to sum two columns to get the third column. If a row has `NULL` for both columns, I want the third column to have `NULL`, instead of a `0`. The reason is because I want to get the average of the third column and having a `0` will change that average.

```
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
|--------|--------|--------|
| 10     | NULL   | 10     |
| 20     | NULL   | 20     |
| NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
| 20     | 30     | 50     |
| NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
```

I have tried the following approaches, but they all give a `0` for `NULL` rows. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
CREATE TABLE #AMOUNTS (
    Value1 INT,
    Value2 INT
)

INSERT INTO #AMOUNTS VALUES
(10, NULL), (20, NULL), (NULL, NULL), (20, 30), (NULL, NULL)

SELECT 
Value1, Value2

,ISNULL(Value1, 0) + ISNULL(Value2, 0) AS Value3
,COALESCE(Value1, 0) + COALESCE(Value2, 0) AS Value3
,CASE WHEN Value1 = NULL AND Value2 = NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE ISNULL(Value1, 0) + ISNULL(Value2, 0)
END AS Value3
FROM #AMOUNTS
```

```
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value3 | Value3 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 10     | NULL   | 10     | 10     | 10     |
| 20     | NULL   | 20     | 20     | 20     |
| NULL   | NULL   | 0      | 0      | 0      |
| 20     | 30     | 50     | 50     | 50     |
| NULL   | NULL   | 0      | 0      | 0      |
```

Comment: `Value1 = NULL` will never be true, `NULL` doesn't equal anything, including `NULL`. YOu need `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing for NULL use operator `IS` not `=`:

```
CASE WHEN Value1 IS NULL AND Value2 IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE ISNULL(Value1, 0) + ISNULL(Value2, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when value1 is null and value2 is null
             then null
             else coalesce(value1, 0) + coalesce(value2, 0)
        end)
```

That said, `apply` is a simple way to get the average:

```
select t.*, v.avg_value
from t cross apply
     (select avg(v.val) as avg_value
      from (values (value1), (value2)) v(val)
     ) v;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `0`s in the result column you can do it with `ISNULL()` and `NULLIF()`:

```
SELECT *, NULLIF(ISNULL(Value1, 0) + ISNULL(Value2, 0), 0) Value3
FROM Amounts
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4543622826111be0d38c5cb596a0a5f).